# Run target once for built project

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I have a msbuild script that compiles the files and then copies them to a different directory. To ensure only the freshly built files are in the destination, I want to delete the destination folder before.

I tried running it before the Build target like this

```
<Target Name="RemoveRelease64" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64' and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(SolutionDir)bin64" />
</Target>
```

But this is called for every project that my main project depends on. When starting a build for Project A, it first builds Project B, C and D. For every built project the target is called and the folder deleted. As such it deletes the folder too often.

Is there a way to call a target only once for the project that the build got started for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to call a target only once for the project that the
> build got started for?

I think you use [Directory.Build.props or Directory.Build.targets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#directorybuildprops-and-directorybuildtargets) as the msbuild script and write the `RemoveRelease64` in that file.

If you put the file in the solution folder, as its scope, it will works for the projects from current folder and any sub folders.

**So as a suggestion**, if you want the **msbuild script** to only work for project `A` rather than any referenced projects `B`,`C`,`D`, you should put the msbuild script only in the project folder of A where `A.csproj` file exists .

**Suggestion**

**1)** If you use `Directory.Build.props` or `Directory.Build.targets`, delete it at the solution folder or any parent directories, add it only in the folder of Project A where `A.csproj` file exists.

**2) Besides**, you could abandon using `Directory.Build.props/targets` file. **Instead**, you could rename it as `RemoveRelease64.targets` and please remember not to use those two names.

Use [msbuild import node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/import-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019) in `A.csproj` file and then it will only executes for **Project A** rather than `B`,`C`,`D`:

Add this in `A.csproj` file and remove any `Directory.Build.props` or `Directory.Build.targets` in solution folders and project folders.

```
<Import Project="xxx\RemoveRelease64.targets" />
```

Comment: Thanks the import is what I was missing